# How to write the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have this Number in my table in Column X = '054939393000' (data Type : string) this number is the combination of four fields in other table.. How to compare these two tables with this combination?

```
A, B , C and D

A field will have first three letter '054'
B field will have '9393'
C field has '93'
D filed has '000'
```

How to write the sql query to check these fields against the other table? in other table these fields have four different columns..

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of X? string or int?

Comment: Sorry it has type string

Comment: @RagingBull i believe an int would not have the single quotes ??

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille: The code part of the question is not actually the code. He is explaining the idea or the situation. So I believed the single quotes were for better understanding.

Comment: yeah that could also be true :))..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it using `Substring`.

Check the fields like:

```
WHERE A=SUBSTRING(X,1,3)
  AND B=SUBSTRING(X,4,4)
  AND C=SUBSTRING(X,8,2)
  AND D=SUBSTRING(X,11,3)
```

Syntax:

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

Read more about `SUBSTRING` [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can concat the 4 columns and compare it against single column i.e.

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.x = CONCAT(tbl2.A,tbl2.B,tbl2.C,tbl2.D)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the SubString function

SUBSTRING(field, start, length)

```
A = SUBSTRING(X, 1, 3) and
B = SUBSTRING(X, 4, 4) and
C = SUBSTRING(X, 8, 2) and
D = SUBSTRING(X, 11, 3)
```